# Commerce: Setting Custom Form Default Values

Tags: forms, commerce

I would like to set custom default values for both the Customer Shipping and Billing forms. I built a custom page/pane that occurs at the beginning of the Commerce Checkout process. This page/pane has 5 fields that pull basic user information before depositing the user at the 'express' checkout form (part 2 in the multi-step form -- or better known as the typical Shipping/Billing forms). My objective is to be able to use the data saved in $form_state['order']->data; in order to pass it into the default_values in certain textfields within the Shipping/Billing forms.

Using hook_form_alter does nothing to modify the Shipping/Billing in either $form_state or $form. There doesn't appear to be a declaration of default_value within the forms. Even if I do declare a value/values, it does not show up on the page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use

function hook_field_widget_addressfield_standard_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, &$context) { }

Comment: This is a known issue for the addressfield module, and was solved via v1.2. See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2392855